# Nested select behavior and efficiency

Tags: halide

I have four Funcs A, B, C, D I wish to interleave ((0,0) is upper left):

```
A B A B ...
C D C D ...
A B A B ...
C D C D ...
...
```

So, I have something like:

```
Func out;              // why can't this be on the same line as the implementation?
out(x, y) = select((x&1)==0, 
               select((y&1)==0, A(x/2,y/2), C(x/2,y/2)),
               select((y&1)==0, B(x/2,y/2), D(x/2,y/2)) );
```

Is there a better (more efficient) way of doing this? I note that A,B,C,D contain a few select()'s as well (they are very nonlinear Funcs.)

In the same regard, I have this structure inside A:

```
Func choose0, choose1, a0, a1, a2, A;

choose0, choose1, a0, a1, a2 = something complicated...;

A(x,y) = select(choose0(x,y), a0(x,y), select(choose1(x,y), a1(x,y), a2(x,y)));
```

Will Halide be generating code that computes a0, a1, and a2 prior to select? I'd really rather that only the chosen Func be computed for any specific value of (x,y).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you say:

```
out.unroll(x, 2)
   .unroll(y, 2)
   .bound(x, 0, input.width())
   .bound(y, 0, input.height());
```

Then the selects should go away in the first example. You're telling Halide to unroll by a factor of two, and that counting starts at zero (so it knows to start with A).

In the second example, Halide will indeed evaluate both sides of a select - otherwise vectorization doesn't work very well. The trick is to make those evaluations cheap (just loads) by computing the a* Funcs somewhere:

```
a0.compute_at(A, x);
a1.compute_at(A, x);
a2.compute_at(A, x);
```

I chose to compute them at x, because that way the condition that determines whether or not they're used (choose*(x, y)) is constant for the lifetime of their computation (a single value of x, y). Halide should detect this and jam their computation in an if statement for you.

Comment: Ahh, I see how the first works. The compiler is smart enough to know that the LSB of x and y are fixed in the unrolled code, and thus, that only one branch of the select will be triggered, and thus the select can be removed.

I'm still not quite following your argument for the second case yet. Wouldn't using y work as well?

Comment: For a fixed value of y, whether or not you need a0, a1, a2 varies, because the condition choose0(x, y) depends on x. So Halide will just compute an entire scanline of each a* if you use compute_at(A, y)